# xslt Ant Task not passing parameters to my stylesheet

Tags: ant

I have a style sheet like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="testParam"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="resources/integer[@name='LOG_LEVEL']/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$testParam"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I have an input xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="LOG_LEVEL">3</integer>
    <string name="app_name">Test Application</string>
</resources>
```

But when I try to call an xslt transform in ant using this:

```
<xslt in="in.xml" out="out.xml" style="style_above.xsl">
    <outputproperty name="method" value="xml"/>
    <outputproperty name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <outputproperty name="indent" value="yes"/>
    <param name="testParam" expression="test"/>
</xslt>
```

I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="LOG_LEVEL"/>
    <string name="app_name">Test Application</string>
</resources>
```

it doesn't seem to be changing my xslt parameter to the value I specify in my ant target

Comment: I'm using ANT 1.8.2 by the way

Comment: It works just fine. Tested it with ant 1.8.2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, i figured out the problem was a different thing. Was about to update this was too late. I defined the xslt task in a macro and have a optional element also named param and that was the culprit. Thanks